# Run VBA code on specific time

Tags: excel, vba

I found the following code on this web site "save Excel file as CSV" is there any way with help of you'll I can auto run this code on specific time (11:00 pm every night), and save file name as current date (hr2015-05-05), any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFileName As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
TempFileName = Sourcewb.FullName + ".csv"

'Copy the sheet to a new workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Save the new workbook and close it
With Destwb
    .SaveAs Filename:=TempFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
End Sub
```

Edit fixed tag issue

Comment: Do you have access to use Windows Task scheduler?

Comment: The absolute best way would be to utilize Powershell and Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Yes I have access to Windows Task Scheduler, but how the Task Scheduler will run the VBA code and save the file with current date?

Answer (score 7):

I would do this one of two ways.

One would be through windows task scheduler. Where you will set up a task to open Excel and run it that way. See http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/302970-task-scheduler-vbulletin-script-auto-open-excel.html

Or

Use the code

`Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:00:00"), SUBNAMEHERE`

Changing `SUBNAMEHERE` to the sub where the code is. Not sure if it will run the beforesave part through

EDIT added code to have filename

Change `TempFileName = Sourcewb.FullName + ".csv"` to be

`TempFileName = Sourcewb.FullName & " hr" & format(now,"YYYY-MM-DD") & ".csv"`

Comment: If you use the second option, wouldn't you basically have to open Excel, run the Macro and then Excel would essentially be frozen, waiting for 2300?  Or can you still use Excel while running a macro waiting on that TimeValue?

Comment: @user3578951, excel will not be frozen.

Comment: Nice solution. I don't see a point in putting this code in `BeforeSave` in any case.

Comment: @user3578951 just a reminder that you will need to make sure that excel remains open for the `application.ontime` to work. And also make sure that you run it each time, so consider putting it in the workbook open event or something like that

Comment: @dePatinkin Thanks. Yeah with this code I would have it at a seperate sub

Comment: I added the code in workbook open event, I can use the Task Scheduler to open the workbook, the only thing remain the file name, i want to use "hr2015-05-06" format. the date is current date.

Comment: @user3877643 what does the `hr` stand for? Hour? Or do you just want it to say `hr TODAYSDATE`. And do you want the brackets in it as well?

Comment: its a Text, stand for Human Resources. hrYYYY-MM-DD format if possible.

Comment: TempFileName = Sourcewb.Path & "\hr" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".csv"
I changed the file name and change the code as above, its work perfectly.